# AS3 removeChild The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I've got a problem, here is the code I'm using

```
    public var monsterArray:Array;
    public var score:Number;

    public function MonsterManager()
    {
        score = 0;
        monsterArray = new Array();
    }

public function spawnMonster( waveNumber:Number ):void
    {
        //This code needs to choose the ID not the monster itself
        var id:Number;
        var meleeRanged = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
        trace("meleeRanged :"+meleeRanged);
        id = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
        switch(id)
        {
            case 1: var newMonster1:Monster1 = new Monster1();
                        newMonster1.monsterSetup( waveNumber, id );
                        monsterArray.push( newMonster1 );
                        addChild( newMonster1 );
                break;
        }

    }

public function update(  ):void
    {
        //trace("Go To Update");
        var i:number;
        i = 0;
        for each ( var monster:Monster in monsterArray )
        //monster needs a bool variable to say if it is active, if it is dont reuse,
        //if it is not activate, we can use setup and re use it,
        {
            monster.update( );
            if(monster.hp <= 0)
            {
                score += 10;
                removeChild( monster );
                array.splice(i,1);
                //monster.x = -1000;
                //monster.hp = 1;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have deleted the add text function, because that doesn't cause the problem :), but when i call apon the removeText function, i get this error in flash

```
The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
```

The array is public, so I'm not sure why it can't be deleted, could someone show some light on this please.

Cheers.

New code below

```
  public function update( heroGra:HeroDisplay ):void
    {
        //trace("Go To Update");
        var count:Number = monsterArray.length;
        var monster:Monster;

        for( var i:int = 0; i<count; i++)
        {
            monster = monsterArray[i];
            monster.update( heroGra );


            if( monster.hp <= 0 )
            {
                score += 10;
                removeChild( monster );
                monsterArray.splice(i,1);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Canvas.

If there is more than 2 monsters in the monsterArray a error occurs, any idea on how i can get it to stop this?

Comment: `removeChild()` is used to remove something from the stage (ie: something on screen that you can see). You cannot remove something that you've never added before (you use  `addChild()` to add something). Are you intending to remove something from the Array or the stage? You might want to show more of your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your for each function is doing a good job. Try to do it this way:

```
public function update(  ):void
{
    var count:Number = monsterArray.length;
    var monster:Monster;

    for( var i:int = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        monster = monsterArray[i];
        monster.update( );

        if(monster.hp <= 0)
        {
            score += 10;
            removeChild( monster );
            array.splice(i,1);
            count--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, there is a method called addText, this adds some text to the array, I updated my question

Comment: i do apologize that me amend that above :D

Comment: you can't addChild String to DisplayList because it's not a DisplayObject. Create TextField instead...

Comment: That should be better, this code is taken from another piece of work

Comment: I will try in abit, need to cook myself some food :D

Comment: Now im getting this "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.", it is saying the line monster.update( heroGra );
 is null